# How to switch icon to text into ToggleGroup?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui

There is `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` with 4 `MaterialButton` and horizontal orientation. Some device's screens can't show all buttons in row. Thus I want to show only icons, but for selected button add text. Is it possible with style? Preferably with animation.

Now:

[image]

Target:

[image]

[image]

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    android:id="@+id/rename_toggle_group"
    style="@style/CustomButtonToggleGroup"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_indent_vertical_min"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:checkedButton="@id/rename_current"
    app:selectionRequired="true"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/rename_current"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        style="@style/MaterialButtonSecondaryToggle"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_general"
        android:text="Current" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/rename_top"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_general"
        style="@style/MaterialButtonSecondaryToggle" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/rename_bottom"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        style="@style/MaterialButtonSecondaryToggle"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_general"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/rename_all"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        style="@style/MaterialButtonSecondaryToggle"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_general" />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and worked for me

```
private fun setupToggleGroup() {
    val (checkedButton, text) = getTogglePair(binding.renameToggleGroup.checkedButtonId)
    checkedButton?.text = text.toString()

    binding.renameToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { group, checkedId, isChecked ->
        val (button, text) = getTogglePair(checkedId)
        button?.text = if (isChecked) text.toString() else ""
    }
}

private fun getTogglePair(checkedButtonId: Int): Pair<MaterialButton?, String?> {
    return when (checkedButtonId) {
        binding.renameCurrent.id -> Pair(binding.renameCurrent , getString(R.string.rename_current))
        binding.renameTop.id -> Pair(binding.renameTop , getString(R.string.rename_top))
        binding.renameBottom.id -> Pair(binding.renameBottom , getString(R.string.rename_bottom))
        binding.renameAll.id -> Pair(binding.renameAll , getString(R.string.rename_all))
        else -> Pair(null, null)
    }
}
```

call setupToggleGroup() in onCreate of the Activity